# Why do tmux and oh-my-zsh both break color output from git log under WSL?

Tags: git, tmux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, oh-my-zsh

I recently decided to try out WSL (Ubuntu 18.04), and I installed zsh+oh-my-zsh, as I usually do. Pretty quickly I discovered that color output from `git log` is broken:

- Git log output, uncolorized

[image: Git log output, uncolorized]

The color-codes appear to be correct, and piping this output to cat does result in the correct colors being displayed. Other commands, including some git commands, such as `git status`, display colors correctly.

I eventually discovered that this didn't occur under bash. However, opening a new terminal running bash, then launching zsh, then launching bash, will result in the innermost bash instance inheriting the broken behavior from zsh.

- bash -> zsh -> bash

[image: bash -> zsh -> bash]

I also discovered that this behavior is provoked by oh-my-zsh. Colors are displayed correctly in zsh with its vanilla configuration.

Unfortunately, this problem isn't confined to oh-my-zsh. I get exactly the same behavior from `git log` within tmux, regardless of which shell is used and which shell tmux was launched from.

I'm primarily using the `ys` oh-my-zsh theme, but I tried out several, and these problems don't seem to be confined to any single one.

`TERM` is set to `xterm-256color` in zsh and bash, and `screen` in tmux.

Let me know if there's any other info that would help, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Try your same setup in any Windows terminal emulator. For example, wsltty, ConEmu etc. If those shows correct output then the issue lies in cmd.exe.

Comment: WSL TTY behaves in exactly the same way, except now I can't trigger this behavior using tmux in any terminal emulator. I'm not sure what happened to change that, but maybe I should take this to the oh-my-zsh issue tracker instead, since that project seems to be the only way I can consistently trigger this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this had nothing to do with WSL. I had misconfigured `LESS=-XF`, when I should have set `LESS=-XFR`. Because of the `-F`, I didn't even realize `less` was being invoked by `git log`.